# Return number of rows that are in my left join table 1, T-SQL?

Tags: sql, instance, teradata

I need to specify one return result for a left join where the table has multiple duplicates. The query is already robust so I'm having a hard time with placement.

I think I need to use partition by but I haven't gotten any of my attempts to run. `Max(T2.ord_creatd_dt)` didn't run.

Query:

```
SELECT  
    T1.EMAIL, T2.BILLG_STATE_CD, T2.BILLG_ZIP_CD, T2.ord_creatd_dt
FROM
    (SELECT EMAIL
     FROM SJ_FPQ_Q1_19
     UNION
     SELECT EMAIL
     FROM SJ_FPQ_Q2
     UNION
     SELECT email AS EMAIL
     FROM Amber_10182019) AS T1
LEFT JOIN 
    ORD_MSTR As T2 ON T1.EMAIL = T2.EMAIL_ADDR
WHERE 
    T2.ord_creatd_dt > DATE '2018-01-01' 
    AND T2.ord_creatd_dt < DATE '2019-11-08'
```

Returned Results:

```
service@lip.com NY  108012233   11/4/2019
none            ?       ?       4/9/2018
```

I only want one result for each email in T1.

Comment: If there are multiple matches in T2 then which row do you want?

Comment: Preferably the first one with an actual result, although that might be wishing for the stars. The blank cells have question marks in them (?) -> I'll post a data sample.

Comment: Define "first". By definition a table is an unordered set. Maybe ord_creatd_dt?

Comment: The first row that actually has a state or zip code.

Comment: The Left Join in your query is changed to an Inner Join by the optimizer (due to the Where-conditon on T2). Which table is the optional one, T1 or T2? And how do decide which row is returned, based on which column? You should add some example rows and expected result

Answer (score 0):

You can use the apply operator for this. Your Code becomes:

```
SELECT  T1.EMAIL, T2.BILLG_STATE_CD, T2.BILLG_ZIP_CD, T2.ord_creatd_dt
    FROM
    (
        SELECT  EMAIL
            FROM    SJ_FPQ_Q1_19
            UNION
    SELECT  EMAIL
            FROM    SJ_FPQ_Q2
            UNION
    SELECT  email As EMAIL
        FROM    Amber_10182019) As T1
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 * 
    FROM ORD_MSTR As TA 
    WHERE TA.ord_creatd_dt > CAST('2018-01-01' AS date)
      AND TA.ord_creatd_dt < CAST('2019-11-08' AS date)
      AND T1.EMAIL =TA.EMAIL_ADDR
    ORDER BY TA.ord_creatd_dt ASC
) AS T2
```

In this case I've set the ORDER BY clause so that the earliest matching record is returned, you can change this for some other logic if needed.

Note that while this approach is flexible it may be slow for large data sets. Using Row_Number to rank duplicates and taking the first might be better in these situations.

Comment: The APPLY Operator is not available. Thanks for the response though!!

Comment: What version of SQL server are you using?

Comment: T-SQL, Teradata.

Comment: Teradata is neither SQL Server nor T-SQL. I have updated your question to reflect that.

Comment: Well I promise you I am working in Teradata using T-SQL...so there is that.

Comment: @AmberWilliams: You're using Teradata SQL, but it's not abbreviated as T-SQL (which is the *SQL Server* dialect)